# Not able to connect to cube

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, ssas, olap-cube

Not able to connect to Cube.

Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="OLAPConnectionString" providerName="MSOLAP"
    connectionString="Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=reportingCube; integrated security=true"></add>
```

Following error:
     An equal sign was expected after index 0 in the connection string.

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The format should be using `Provider`  & not `ProviderName` as  well some more corrections as below.

```
<add name="OLAPConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=MSOLAP;
Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=OMS; Integrated Security=True"/>
```

Check [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954207.aspx). This [Another Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2304/ADO-Connection-Strings) also describes the same.